# How to identify iOS device with Unique id, For Blocking and UnBlocking the Device

Tags: ios8, udid

All,

My Requirement is i want to add List of iOS devices in my account and only those devices will have access to use app. Earlier we have the UDID access so we can take the UDID from the iTunes Store and add it manually and then using iOS SDK also we can access the UDID and compare both,

But in the latest SDK's seems Apple rejecting the apps which are accessing the UDID using SDK.

What component is Unique and what item i can use. Can any one let me know

Comment: have you tried to use, 'VendorIdentifier' ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW49

Comment: If you have iAds in your application,  then you can also make use of 'advertisingIdentifier' from AdSupport framework.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, For me i want to add the Address before we use the Device, like UDID, we can get when we connect to iTunes, Can we get the 'VendorIIdentifier' and "advertisingIdentifier" before.

Comment: The "AdvertisingIdentifier" can be disabled in the iPhone settings, so it's not a good idea to use it.